# KVC compliance for numbers in NSManagedObject subclass (CoreData)

Tags: core-data, numbers, key-value-coding

I'm trying a basic test of sorting an NSManagedObject subclass. I set up a basic subclass "TestClass" with two attributes: `stringField` and `numberField`. They use the standard Obj-C 2.0 accessor protocol:

```
@interface TestClass : NSManagedObject
@property (retain) NSString *stringField;
@property (retain) NSNumber *numberField;
@end

@implementation TestClass
@dynamic stringField;
@dynamic numberField;
@end
```

When I try to fetch instances of this entity, I can fetch based on either attribute. However, if I use a sort descriptor, the `numberField` is said to not be KVC-compliant.

Within the model, I set the `numberField` to Int64, but I'm confused. I thought the wrapper (NSNumber) would handle the KVC problem. What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Some initial "Is the computer on?"-type questions:

1. Does your model specify that the managed object class for your entity is TestClass?
2. Are you sure you spelled `numberField` correctly when specifying the key in your sort descriptor?
3. Is `numberField` a transient attribute in your model?

These are the common issues that I can think of that might cause such an error when fetching with a sort descriptor, the first one especially.

Also, this won't affect KVC, but your attributes' property declarations should be `(copy)` rather than `(retain)` since they're "value" classes that conform to the `NSCopying` protocol and may have mutable subclasses.  You don't want to pass a mutable string in and mutate it underneath Core Data.  (Yeah, there's no NSMutableNumber or NSMutableDate in Cocoa, but that doesn't prevent creating MyMutableNumber or MyMutableDate subclasses...)

Comment: Yes, it does specify that the MO class is TestClass. No, not transient. The error was #2. Bad spelling (numberKey instead of numberfield). How stupid. Thanks!
Also took note about copy. Thanks.

Comment: (copy) is the right attribute, except in NSManagedObject subclasses where "The property accessor methods Core Data generates are by default (nonatomic, retain)—this is the recommended configuration." and " You should use copy sparingly as it increases overhead." [Source: Apple's Core Data Programming Guide >> Managed Object Accessor Methods]